# R: How to make a boxplot with lines connecting paired points between them

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, boxplot

I have the following dataframe:

```
puck <- c("C125a", "C130a", "H100a", "H106a", "L12a", "L15a", "C125b", "C130b", "H100b", "H106b", "L12b", "L15b")
habitat <- c("C", "C", "H", "H", "L", "L","C", "C", "H", "H", "L", "L")
treatment <- c("light", "light", "light", "light", "light", "light", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark")
colony <- c("C125", "C130", "H100", "H106", "L12", "L15", "C125", "C130", "H100", "H106", "L12", "L15")
resid <- c(0.200214909, -0.337518783, 0.053515029, 0.208246923, -0.193085211, -0.378099508, 0.336090273, -0.345066464, 0.001808814, -0.267078962, 0.049018966,0.383408025)
wt <- cbind(puck,habitat,treatment,colony,resid)
```

I would like to make a boxplot with the habitat on the x-axis, residuals on the y-axis and separated by treatment. I would then like to overlay the points on the box plot with lines connecting the paired points between treatment (like this:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUPhm.png))

I tried the following code:
ggplot(data = wt, aes(x=Habitat,y=resid, color = Treatment))+
geom_point(aes(color = Treatment),position=position_jitterdodge(jitter.width=0),alpha=0.5)+
geom_line(aes(group = OG_colonyID))+
geom_boxplot(alpha=1)
but I am just getting a single vertical line between the box plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One potential option is to plot both treatment and habitat on the x-axis using `interaction()`, e.g.

```r
library(ggplot2)

puck <- c("C125a", "C130a", "H100a", "H106a", "L12a", "L15a", "C125b", "C130b", "H100b", "H106b", "L12b", "L15b")
habitat <- c("C", "C", "H", "H", "L", "L","C", "C", "H", "H", "L", "L")
treatment <- c("light", "light", "light", "light", "light", "light", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark")
colony <- c("C125", "C130", "H100", "H106", "L12", "L15", "C125", "C130", "H100", "H106", "L12", "L15")
resid <- c(0.200214909, -0.337518783, 0.053515029, 0.208246923, -0.193085211, -0.378099508, 0.336090273, -0.345066464, 0.001808814, -0.267078962, 0.049018966,0.383408025)
wt <- data.frame(puck,habitat,treatment,colony,resid)

ggplot(data = wt, aes(x=interaction(treatment, habitat, sep = " "),
                      y = resid, color = treatment))+
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_line(aes(group = colony), color = "black") + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha=1) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 18) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Would that work for your use-case?

---

Or perhaps using `facet_wrap()` to separate by habitat?

```r
library(ggplot2)

puck <- c("C125a", "C130a", "H100a", "H106a", "L12a", "L15a", "C125b", "C130b", "H100b", "H106b", "L12b", "L15b")
habitat <- c("C", "C", "H", "H", "L", "L","C", "C", "H", "H", "L", "L")
treatment <- c("light", "light", "light", "light", "light", "light", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark", "dark")
colony <- c("C125", "C130", "H100", "H106", "L12", "L15", "C125", "C130", "H100", "H106", "L12", "L15")
resid <- c(0.200214909, -0.337518783, 0.053515029, 0.208246923, -0.193085211, -0.378099508, 0.336090273, -0.345066464, 0.001808814, -0.267078962, 0.049018966,0.383408025)
wt <- data.frame(puck,habitat,treatment,colony,resid)

ggplot(data = wt, aes(x = treatment,
                      y = resid, color = treatment))+
  geom_point()+ 
  geom_line(aes(group = colony), color = "black") + 
  geom_boxplot(alpha=1) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 18) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top") +
  facet_wrap(~habitat, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>